# Conditions on couples of elements to generate the same ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain. The following is a well known fact:

> Let $a,b \in R$. Then $(a)=(b)$ if and only if there exist a unit $u \in R$ such that $a=ub$.

I would like to generalize this result for ideals which are generated by two elements. So the question is:

> Let $a,a',b,b' \in R$. Does it exist some property for these four elements which is equivalent on having $(a,b)=(a',b')$?

I know that maybe this question is a bit vague, I hope that somebody could give me some reference or hint.

EDIT: As Mathmo123's comment suggests, maybe the condition could be

> There exists $U \in GL_2(R)$ such that $$\left[ \begin{matrix} a \\ b\end{matrix} \right] = U \left[ \begin{matrix} a' \\ b'\end{matrix} \right]$$

Clearly, this is a sufficient condition. But is it necessary as well?

Comment: Do you have reason to think that such a condition exists in general? I'm struggling to convince myself that a "nice" condition on elements should exist if, for example, $R$ is not a UFD.

Comment: @Mathmo123 No, I have no reason to believe that a nice condition exists: this question came to my mind without having read it anywhere. It turned out that an answer to this question would be very useful for my current work.

Comment: Thinking again, could you not create a condition of the form $(a,b) = (a',b')$ if and only if there exists an invertible matrix in $A\in \mathrm{GL}_2(R )$ such that $[a,b]^T = A[a',b']^T$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 What a great guess!

Comment: It should be because $(a,b)=(a',b')$ implies $a=k_1.a'+l_1.b'$ and $b=k_2.a'+l_2.b'$ which gives the invertible matrix condition if we solve.

Comment: @NeerajKumar things can go wrong if you're not in a UFD - for example, in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, the ideals $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(4, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ are equal (since $2 = 4\cdot 2-(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$). But the obvious choice of transition matrix is $\mathrm{diag}(2,1)$ which is not invertible. It is possible for there to be a non-invertible matrix $A$ with $A(a,b) = (a,b)$. But still this doesn't mean that there does not exist an invertible transition matrix.

Comment: In the above example, $\begin{bmatrix}4\\ 1+\sqrt{-5}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1-\sqrt{-5} \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\ 1+\sqrt{-5}\end{bmatrix}$ gives an example where the matrix is invertible.

Comment: (My above reasoning for what can go wrong is incorrect - it can also go wrong in a UFD! The real issue is that invertible in $R$ is not the same as invertible in $\mathrm{Frac}(R )$, and there is no guarantee that the transition matrix will be unique, even in a UFD, since $(a,b)$ will not be a free $R$ module)

Answer (score 4):

We consider the following condition.

> **Condition.** There exists $A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(R)$ such that
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} a' \\ b'\end{pmatrix}.$$

The sufficiency of the condition has already been noted, so I will only consider its necessity.

> **Lemma.** If $R$ is a Dedekind domain, then the condition is necessary.

*Proof.* Let $I = (a,b) = (a',b')$. If $I = 0$, we are trivially done. If $I \neq 0$, then $I$ is locally free of rank $1$: every localisation is a DVR, so $I_\mathfrak p \subseteq R_\mathfrak p$ is principal, hence free of rank 1. Thus, $I$ is projective, and the sequence
$$0 \to K \to R^2 \stackrel{(a,b)}\longrightarrow I \to 0$$
splits. Hence, $K$ is projective as well, and taking determinants (top wedges) we get $K \otimes I = R$. We get the same for $K'$ (replacing $(a,b)$ by $(a',b')$), so we deduce that $K \cong K'$ (abstractly, not necessarily as submodules of $R^2$), since $I$ is invertible. We get a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & \xrightarrow{} & K & \xrightarrow{} & R^2 & \xrightarrow{} & I & \xrightarrow{} & 0\\
 & & \downarrow & &  & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \xrightarrow{} & K' & \xrightarrow{} & R^2 & \xrightarrow{} & I & \xrightarrow{} & 0
\end{array}$$
where the two vertical arrows are isomorphisms. Choosing splittings of the top and bottom rows, we can construct an isomorphism $R^2 \to R^2$ making the diagram commutative.

**Remark.** Even for $R = k[x,y]$, the condition is not necessary! Indeed, consider the ideal $I = (x^2,y) = (x^2, (x+1)y)$. Then a choice of transition matrices (for the two directions) is given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & x+1 \end{pmatrix}, & & \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ y & -x+1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
We will show that there is no invertible matrix $A$ such that $A\ (x^2,y)^\top = (x^2, xy + y)^\top$. Indeed, any such matrix differs from the [first] matrix above by
$$\begin{pmatrix}-yP & x^2P \\ -yQ & x^2Q \end{pmatrix}$$
for some $P, Q \in k[x,y]$, because $k[x,y]$ is a UFD. We have to show that no such matrix can be invertible. But if we reduce mod $y$, we get the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & x^2P \\ 0 & 1+x+x^2Q \end{pmatrix}.$$
The determinant is $1+x+x^2Q$, which can never be a unit in $k[x]$.

**Remark.** So we see that our condition is the correct one for Dedekind domains, and is too strong even for a UFD of dimension $2$. There are a few directions we could take from here:

- Try to find a better criterion. I'm not sure if we will be able to come up with one, though.
- Analyse the problem for more than $2$ generators. It seems that we have fundamentally used the fact that $K$ is locally free of rank $1$ to conclude that $K \cong K'$; thus one would imagine that there might exist counterexamples for Dedekind domains (maybe even for a PID) for more than $2$ generators.

**Edit:** Maybe I should comment a bit on where this example comes from. The ideals $(a,b), (a,c)$ coincide if and only if $\bar b, \bar c \in R/(a)$ differ by a unit. Thus, a lift of the unit and its inverse give lower triangular matrices taking one vector to the other. If $R$ is a UFD, then any two matrices taking $(a,b)$ to $(a,c)$ differ by a matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}-bP & aP \\ -bQ & aQ \end{pmatrix}.$$
Reducing mod $b$, the same method as above applies whenever the unit that $\bar b$ and $\bar c$ differ by does not lift to an element whose reduction mod $b$ is a unit. In the example above, the unit is $x+1 \in k[x,y]/(x^2)$; none of its lifts become constant mod $y$.

In summary, the obstruction is somehow related to liftability of units.

If you want a more arithmetic example, you can take $(5,X) = (5, 2X) \subseteq \mathbb Z[X]$. The unit $2 \in \mathbb F_5[X]$ does not lift to any polynomial whose constant term is a unit in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that we didn't use Noetherianity of $R$, so maybe this is true for Prufer domains as well? Moreover, I don't get the inclusion $(x^2, xy+y) \subseteq (x^2,y)$: how can we get $y$ from $x^2, xy+y$?

Comment: Maybe you want to ask about the inclusion $(x^2,xy+y)\supseteq(x^2,y)$. (Well, you can start from $1=x^2-(x^2-1)$.)

Comment: Right; I even wrote down the matrix that takes you there!

I think you might be right about Prüfer domains; any finitely generated ideal is projective, so the sequence splits and the kernel is also finitely generated (this is not clear a priori).

Answer (score 1):

Concerning domains, there is a nice partial result covering the case where the ideal is principal.

> **Lemma.** Let $R$ be a domain, and let $a,b,x\in R$ be elements of $R$. The following are equivalent :
>
> 1. $\langle a,b\rangle = \langle x\rangle$
> 2. There exists $P=\begin{pmatrix}u & v \\ -b' & a'\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ with $\det(P)=1$, such that $\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}=P\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$

This is (part of) Theorem 1.1, chapter IV in [Modules sur les anneaux commutatifs](https://www.amazon.fr/Modules-sur-anneaux-commutatifs-exercices/dp/2916352333), G.-M. Diaz-Toca, H. Lombardi, C. Quitté.

**Proof.** The case where $x=0$ is trivial, so we assume $x\neq 0$.

(1)$\implies$(2). By hypothesis there exist $u,v\in R$ and $a',b'\in R$ such that $ua+vb=x$, $xa'=a$ and $xb'=b$. Then one also has $0=ab-ab=xa'b-xb'a=x(-b'a+a'b)$. Since $R$ is a domain and $x\neq 0$, this implies $-b'a+a'b=0$, thus
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u & v \\ -b' & a'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$$
Furthermore $x=ua+vb=x(ua'+vb')$ and again, since $R$ is a domain and $x\neq 0$ we have $\det(P)=ua'+vb'=1$.

The converse implication (2)$\implies$(1) was already noted in previous posts. $\square$